# Correct mogoose schema for array of object as field value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have below mongoose schema for social post:

```
const PostSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    author: String,
    email: String,
    title: String,
    description: String,
    file: String,
    subGratis: String,
    dateOfPost: String,
    likes: Number,
    claps: Number,
    comments:[
        {
            commentAuthor: String,
            comment: String,
            mention: String,
            dateOfcomment: String,
            replies: [{
                replyAuthor: String,
                reply: String,
                dateOfReply: String
            }]
        }
    ]
},{collection: 'SocialPost'});
```

In my nodejs app, I have in `req.body` all the fields except `comments`. I add comments field as below:

```
req.body.comments=new Array();
```

Then I proceed to save the document as below:

```
var newPost=new SocialPost(req.body);
            console.log(newPost);
            newPost.comments=new Array();
            newPost.save().then((item)=>{
                res.json({"Status":"Success"});
            }).catch(err=>{
                console.log(err);
                res.status(400).json({"Status":"Failure"});
            })
```

I am getting below error:

```
Error: SocialPost validation failed: comments: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong in this code. How can I correct this?

Thank You!

Comment: not sure about the error, but don't initialize it to an empty array, remove this line `req.body.comments=new Array();` and also this `newPost.comments=new Array();` , schema will automatically add empty array in collection..

Comment: So it means I don't need to add comments to ``req.body`` at all?

Comment: You also should use `[]` when initialising an array as `new Array` will be an instance of `Array` and not `object`. (Just a note, other commenter was correct)